# Crystal Reports: Declaring Color Array Variable

Tags: crystal-reports

This seems like a simple question with a simple answer but is there a ColorVar type? I haven't been able to find anything about this anywhere online.

For example,
I create an array of numbers like this:

```
local NumberVar index := 2;
local NumberVar Array numarr := [0,1,2,3];
numarr[index]
```

I would like to create an array of colors in the same way and then index into it later.

I can do something like this:

```
[crBlack, crWhite, color(100, 231, 100), ...][index]
```

This suggests space is being allocated for the color array, is there something like a ColorVar or is it being allocated as a NumberVar or something?

Thanks [MilletSoftware](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1734722/milletsoftware)!
I was able to implement what I was trying to:

```
local numbervar array rowColors := [
    color(234, 247, 255), crWhite,              //Default
    color(255, 196, 232), color(255, 214, 239), //Highlight #1
    color(...), color(...)                      //Highlight #2
];
local numbervar colorIndex := RecordNumber mod 2 + 1 + switch(highlight1case, 2, highlight2case, 4, ..., caseN, 2N, true, 0);
rowColors[colorIndex]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no ColorVar data type in Crystal.

The result of the Color() or RGB() functions is a number. So you can indeed store colors as numbers.

Comment: Thanks, my guess was that it was stored in a different data type. Hopefully that means I can store it in an NumberVar array and then index it later to retrieve a color. I'll have to test it when I get a chance.

Comment: Yes, simply create a formula such as 
RGB(230,230,230) and place it in some section such as the report header.
You will see that it returns a number.